# schedule ssis 2012 parent package in job agent There is no project to reference error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In SSIS 2012, I have two child packages and one parent package which just runs the two children. I can run the parent package no problem in visual studio. Then I created a sql server 2012 job to run the parent package (from file system). And got this error

Description: There is no project to reference.

I am just from SqlServer 2008 and it's used to work fine this way so not sure what changed in 2012?

Comment: Script your jobstep and update your question with the code. If it doesn't actually let you complete the job creation, post a screenshot of the job step editor

Comment: Just found out the server doesn't have SSIS service installed. Could it be the reason? Why I can still run it in VS?